Rafters for shed roof
My shed project (a labor of love) is nearing completion. Well, minus a roof. Shed is made out of cinder blocks (8x8x16) about 12 x12 ft (outside dimensions) and 10/11 blocks tall. The roof will be sloping (one slope) from 11 blocks tall wall to 10 blocks tall wall. I am thinking of putting up a metal roof. I am in the process of putting in J hooks for top plates. What should be the rafters' dimensions? I mean the width and thickness? Obviously they should be at least 13 ft long...  How will I fasten them to the top plates?

Weather conditions expected(hurricanes/tornadoes/snow load) will make a difference on how the roof is attached and the size of rafters needed.  Your local building department will have this information.

@crip659 Here we are talking North-East Ohio, there are 4 seasons with rain and snow.

For snow load you probably want 2x10s or 2x12s for that low slope roof.  Hurricane ties to the building might not be overkill either, for wind.  This is from a non engineer/builder.  checking with locals is recommended.

Lean-to style roof?
